# Javascript substring with escape characters

Tags: javascript

i have a string like the following

```
var string1 = " folder\\subfolder1\\subfolder2 "
```

and i want to replace the "\" with "/" with string1.replace in order to be

```
var string2 = "folder/subfolder1/subfolder2"
```

I tried

```
            var rep = path.replace("\\", "/");
```

but is not working. Any help ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376440/javascript-replacing-the-escape-character-in-a-string-literal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it globally, for example with a regexp literal & the `g` flag;

```
var rep = path.replace(/\\/g, "/");
```

Comment: This replace the "\\" with "//" not "/"

Comment: It replaces a single \ (i.e. \\ in a string literal) with a single / ; http://jsfiddle.net/waZc6/1/ if for some strange reason you have `str = "folder\\\\subfolder1";` then use `/\\\\/g`