# Pass a path as a param to a JS function

Tags: javascript

This code is a simple function call:

```
<input type="submit" name="_eventId_load" onclick="toLoad('2012\9\27\15\2012-09-27T15-05-59-512.00638.eml');" value="Load"/>
```

This is what I receive in the js function:

```
 function toLoad(path) {
    document.getElementById("emailPath").value = escapepath);
}
```

Via firebug, I see that the param `path` contains: `201292-09-27T15-05-59-512.00638.eml`
And after the scape function: `20129%17%0D%812-09-27T15-05-59-512.00638.eml`

The values are completely different. How could I work/edit te `\` before I send it to the js function?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

This is the solution:

```
<input id="filePath-${status.index}" type="hidden" value="${file.path}"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="toLoad('${status.index}'" value="Load"/>
```

These inputs are inside a form, each element is a file. I need `${status.index}` to know which file I want to load. `${file.path}` contains the path I want to replace.

```
function toLoad(index) {
    var emailPath = document.getElementById("filePath-" + index).value.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\");
    document.getElementById("emailPath").value = emailPath;
}
```

The correct input will be included in a div, so I can use it for the final functionallity.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: toLoad != setAttachmentToLoad

Comment: That was a typing error when I wrote the question. In my code it has the same name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\` is an escape character and therefore needs to be duplicated to become a literal `\`, that is, substitute all `\` symbols with `\\` and retry.

See [Javascript - Replacing the escape character in a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376440/javascript-replacing-the-escape-character-in-a-string-literal)

Comment: Thanks. I have still problems, I can not make a call using this:

<input type="submit" name="_eventId_load" onclick="toLoad('2012\9\27\15\2012-09-27T15-05-59-512.00638.eml'.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\"));" value="Load"/>

How could I make it?

Comment: @Blanca: `.replace` does not help here because the string is interpreted *before* you perform the replace. You have literally put ``\\`` instead of ``\`` in your code, i.e. write `'2012\\9\\27...'`.

Comment: @FelixKling is right. This is also explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376440/javascript-replacing-the-escape-character-in-a-string-literal - there is no way of programming your way around this in JavaScript.

If the path is generated in a backend, for instance using PHP, you can do the replace call there. If however you are typing the constant string into the HTML file yourself, the `\` will have to become a `\\` by manually replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

`\` is reserved as an escape character in Javascript for special characters.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/escapesequence.shtml

Escaping `\` itself happens with two `\\`

Answer (score 0):

Use escape and unescape functions
The unescape() function decodes an encoded string.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp

Comment: This does not help me:
unescape('2012\9\27\15\2012-09-27T15-05-59-512.00638.eml'): "20129
2-09-27T15-05-59-512.00638.eml"

Comment: Oh, I see. you have to escape the system \ symbol. Use the \\. Sorry for misunderstanding.