# remove escaped character

Tags: javascript, escaping

I am working with a javascript function that returns a string of XML.  However, within IE I get that string of XML back with escape characters embedded in it e.g. a double quote is a \” 
"
Instead of 
"
Is there an easy way to remove the escaped character sequence items?
Thanks, 
Derek

Answer (score 2):

Before trying to fix this, you should investigate which other characters are being replaced.  For example, when you get a single `\` in other browsers do you get `\\` in IE?

If the standard C escapes are added, then `JSON.parse` will convert sequences like `\"` into `"`, `\\` into `\`, `\n` into a line-feed, etc.

```
'foo\\bar\nbaz"' === JSON.parse('"foo\\\\bar\\nbaz\\""')
```

---

`JSON.parse` is supported natively on most recent browsers, and on IE specifically, back to IE 8.  The [relevant MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) says

> Supported in the following document modes: **Internet Explorer 8 standards, Internet Explorer 9 standards, Internet Explorer 10 standards**. Also supported in Windows Store apps. See Version Information.
>
> Not supported in the following document modes: Quirks, Internet Explorer 6 standards, Internet Explorer 7 standards.

Comment: Hello, other characters that are being replace are tabs to \t and line breaks to \n.  And this is only happening in IE actually not Chrome or Firefox.  I would like to try and use JSON.parse.  Do I need to include a specific library to use it?

Comment: @geoderek, Whether you need a specific library depends on the version of IE.  [MSDN's JSON page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) says `JSON.parse` is "Supported in the following document modes: Internet Explorer 8 standards, Internet Explorer 9 standards, Internet Explorer 10 standards."  If you have the same trouble on IE 6 or IE 7 then https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js or one of the other parsers from JSON.org should work.

Comment: Ok I am trying it now. line of code is JSON.parse(strInfo) which returns the error: Invalid Character.  The variable strInfo is the string of XML which contains the escaped characters.  I am guessing that I am not using JSON.parse correctly.

Comment: @geoderek, Do you have double quotes around the string you are trying to decode?

Comment: Hi Mike, as it turns out the IE debugger was placing these escape characters in the string only in the debug window.  When I alerted the value it didn't contain them.  Thanks for you help.  For now I am on to a new problem which is dealing with JQuery and IE 9 nuances.  Cheers, D

Answer (score 1):

A similar question: [Javascript - Replacing the escape character in a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376440/javascript-replacing-the-escape-character-in-a-string-literal) explains how to replace a escape character. Maybe you could replace the escape character with empty quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript's [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GSUES/):

```
var string1 = "This is a string with all the \\\" characters escaped";

document.write(string1);    // outputs: This is a string with all the \" characters escaped

document.write("<br />");

string1 = string1.replace("\\", "");

document.write(string1);    // outputs: This is a string with all the " characters escaped
```

Comment: I like this approach as it direct. However, it doesn't seem to work in IE version 9 at least.  Open your jsFiddle in IE and see if you get the same issue as me.

Comment: Seems like there can only be one document.write when using jsfiddle in ie... Fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/GSUES/