# Javascript escape backslash in a string

Tags: javascript

I tried to run the following code in chrome console

```
var line = "RewriteRule ^research/research\-facilities/library\.html$ http://test.com [R=301,L]";

var tmp = line.replace(/\\/g, "\\");

console.log(tmp);
```

The output is:

```
RewriteRule ^research/research-facilities/library.html$ http://test.com [R=301,L]
```

The output I need is:

```
RewriteRule ^research/research\\-facilities/library\\.html$ http://test.com [R=301,L]
```

Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `line.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\")`? I.e. replace with *double* backslash?

Comment: If I put var tmp = line.replace(/\\/g, "??"); it is still not working. The problem is /\\/g

Comment: The value contained in the `line` variable doesn't contain any backslash characters.

Comment: @zzzzBov, which means I need to escape the 'escape' character, not sure how to

Comment: @kenpeter You can't. At least not afterwards anyway. The backslash character has already been used to escape a character in the original string. For example, `"\-".length === 1`

Comment: @RGraham, it turns out php is able to do so.

Comment: @kenpeter, PHP was never tagged in this question. Are you generating JS with PHP and not properly escaping the values? That's an entirely different problem and question than what you've stated above.

Comment: @zzzzBov, I rewrote the code above in PHP and it is able to make it working. What I want to understand is if Javascript sees this "RewriteRule ^research/research\-facilities/library\.html$ http://test.com [R=301,L]", there is no way for javascript to escape backslash, unless we manually add double backslashes in the string or pre-process (e.g. add double backslashes to the string in another language).

Comment: @kenpeter, it sounds like you're saying that you're using PHP to incorrectly generate JS source code. If that's the case, then there is no point at which JS has access to the data you're trying to provide it because of a bug in your code generation. Lesson learned: don't generate JS with PHP (or any other language for that matter). It's a bad idea because of how easy it is to get wrong. Instead, use a different data transfer method and you won't run into such issues.

Comment: @zzzzBov, I had rephrased my question. Hopefully, it makes things clean. I never use PHP generate Javascript. What I want to say is, PHP doesn't treat "\" as an escaped character, but Javascript does. I prove this by completely rewrite the Javascript code above in PHP.

Comment: @kenpeter, yes, different languages are different. Congratulations for figuring that out. If you want a backslash in a JavaScript string you need to escape it. If you want a second backslash in a JavaScript string, you need to escape the second one as well. That means if you want a string with a value of ``\\``, you need to write `'\\\\'`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into is that your string of:

```
"RewriteRule ^research/research\-facilities/library\.html$ http://test.com [R=301,L]"
```

has a value of:

```
RewriteRule ^research/research-facilities/library.html$ http://test.com [R=301,L]
```

Backslash characters within a string escape the next character. For characters that have additional meaning they represent other characters, such as `"\n"` meaning a newline. For any other characters, the escape character is dropped.

This means that `'\-'` has a value of `'-'`, and `'\.'` has a value of `'.'`.

If you want the string to contain the proper escape characters, you need to author it that way.

If you want the *value* of the string to be:

```
RewriteRule ^research/research\-facilities/library\.html$ http://test.com [R=301,L]
```

The original string should be:

```
"RewriteRule ^research/research\\-facilities/library\\.html$ http://test.com [R=301,L]"
```

Comment: I am reading line by line from a large file. Each line is like RewriteRule ^research/research\-facilities/library\.html$ http://test.com [R=301,L]. Do I need to put '\\' manually?

Comment: @kenpeter, when reading a file, the variable will contain the *value*. Escaping is used so that you can assign the proper value when hard-coding strings.

Comment: Based on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376440/javascript-replacing-the-escape-character-in-a-string-literal, there is no elegant way to escape backslash in a string, right?

Comment: @kenpeter, I think you're misunderstanding the issue. Replacing a backslash **in a string value** is simple `str.replace(/\\/g, replacement)` is all it takes. The problem is when someone tries to string-build JavaScript--which is a terrible idea--and fails to properly escape the value before wrapping it with quotes.

Comment: If I want to turn "RewriteRule ^research/research\-facilities/library\.html$ http://test.com [R=301,L]" into "RewriteRule ^research/research\\-facilities/library\\.html$ http://test.com [R=301,L]", how do I do it in javascript?  str.replace(/\\/g, '??') doesn't work (see my code above) and I tired it in browser and terminal. As you said "This means that '\-' has a value of '-', and '\.' has a value of '.'", Javascipt never see backslash in a string when it does str.replace(/\\/g, '??')

Comment: @kenpeter, restating your question in a comment isn't going to get you anywhere. Start by elaborating on the exact problem you're trying to solve *by editing your question*. Include details such as what files you've got, and how you think you need to change them.